# How to make high resolution image

Tags: android, image

I have made an app that uses the filter image and save in sdcard it's working good but I want to save image in two resolution high and low, I have never tried on resolution, Any one one can help that how to save in these both resolution? My code is below

```java
private void saveBitmap(Bitmap bmp, String fileName, int resolution, String resolutionQuality) {
    // File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName + ".png");
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "FiltureImages");
    if (!f.exists()) {
        File wallpaperDirectory = new File("/sdcard/FiltureImages/");
        wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
    }
    File file = new File(new File("/sdcard/FiltureImages/"), fileName + resolutionQuality + ".png");
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, resolution, fos);
        Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Image save successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call like this `saveBitmap(bm, "high", "low", 100, 0, "quality");`

Quality range from `0 -100`

**Note:** change `Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG` to  `Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG` beacuse quality works with JPEG format.

```
private void saveBitmap(Bitmap bmp, String fileNameHigh, String fileNameLow, int resolutionHigh, int resolutionLow, String resolutionQuality) {

        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "FiltureImages");
        if (!f.exists()) {
            f.mkdirs();
        }
        File file = new File(f, fileNameHigh + resolutionQuality + ".png");
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
        File file1 = new File(f, fileNameLow + resolutionQuality + ".png");
        if (file1.exists()) {
            file1.delete();
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream high = new FileOutputStream(file);
            FileOutputStream low = new FileOutputStream(file1);

            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, resolutionHigh, high);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, resolutionLow, low);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image save successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image save falid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Komal Thats Great happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a second bitmap with an alternate resolution this way and call `scaledBmp.compress()` into a new file.

```
        Bitmap scaledBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, newWidth, newHeight, false);
```